# Which is the right word to describe the meal tickets for an event?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, american-english

In an international conference, we provide meals to the participants. I don't know what should be put on the tickets:

> 1. Meal Ticket
> 2. Meal Coupon
> 3. Meal Voucher

Would you please tell me which one to use, or any better alternatives?

Comment: If it can be used to pay for the entire cost of the meal, use *ticket*. If it can only be used for part-payment (i.e. to obtain a discount), then use *coupon* or *voucher*.

Comment: @Mick Thank you. It is used for the entire cost of the meal, one per meal, not for discount.

Comment: Notwithstanding @Mick's comment, as far as the UK is concerned, I think, especially if it were a posh affair, that *voucher* would be the more likely term, even if it was for the whole cost of the meal. *Coupon* is rarely used in Britain, probably because it got a bad name from WW2 food rationing.

Comment: The phrase "[meal ticket](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=meal%20ticket)" actually has another meaning associated with it, so I would refrain from using that.

Comment: There is no single, well-defined term for this concept in the US.  The choice between ticket, coupon, and voucher would likely be based on the specific context.

Answer (score 1):

*Meal voucher* is probably the best term for it. *Coupons* suggests that it offers a discount, not that it's exchangeable for a meal. *Meal ticket* has a possibly confusing second meaning.

Comment: What second meaning could you give to a piece of paper with "Meal Ticket" written on it?

Comment: @TonyK - [Meal ticket](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meal%20ticket) has a meaning of "source of regular income", often a source that is somehow less than above-board.  I would guess that it's origin goes back to the Great Depression, when certain organizations would pass out tickets to indigents, good for a free meal.